Salesforce authorization ECDSA-521
I have problem with creating integration with an external system. I have key provided by clients It's a ECDSA-521 key pair, it uses the P-521 curve and its in this format: pkcs8.
They also gave us snippet of code in node js which should help us with an authentication.
const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    'pkcs8',
    Buffer.from(PRIVATE_KEY, 'base64'),
    { name: 'ECDSA', namedCurve: 'P-521' },
    true,
    ['sign'],
  );

const signature = await crypto.subtle.sign(
    { name: 'ECDSA', hash: 'SHA-512' },
    key,
    Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(event)),
  );

const signatureBase64 = Buffer.from(signature).toString('base64');

My apex code currently looks like this:
Blob privateKeyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(keyBase64);
Blob dataToSignBlob = Blob.valueOf(payload);

Blob signed = Crypto.sign('ECDSA-SHA512', dataToSignBlob, privateKeyBlob);
String signatureBase64 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(signed);
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setBody(payload);
req.setHeader('xyz', signatureBase64);
req.setEndpoint('xyz');
req.setMethod('POST');


Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse response = http.send(req);
System.debug(response.getHeaderKeys());
System.debug(response.toString());

I'm receiving always the same result: [Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]
Any ideas what's wrong?

Step 1: byte-level compare signature  generated by node vs Apex - every byte must match. If there's a difference, you can try a few debugging steps such as making sure your key and payload are exactly (byte-level) the same.
